# Aarch64 what is late-forwarding?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, arm64

"Late-forwarding" is mentioned in ["Arm Neoverse E1 Core Software Optimization Guide"](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/swog466751/a/) (as well as in their optimization guides for some other CPU models):

| Instruction Group | Instructions | Exec Latency | Exec Throughput | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Multiply accumulate (32-bit) | MADD, MSUB | 3 (2) | 1 | 2 |
| Multiply accumulate (64-bit) | MADD, MSUB | 5 (4) | 1/3 | 2 |

> (2) Multiply-accumulate pipelines support late-forwarding of accumulate operands from similar μOPs, allowing a typical sequence of multiply-accumulate μOPs to issue one every N cycles (accumulate latency N shown in parentheses).

What does the term "late-forwarding" mean? What sequence of instructions would be subject to late-forwarding (counter-example would also be helpful)?

Comment: I believe it means that when two “similar” multiple-accumulate operations are dependent on one another and run consencutively, the latency is reduced by one cycle.

Comment: Common in multiply then multiply accumulate sequences (think dot products).  Also happens with certain crypto functions on Cortex A chips when calculating AES values or doing PMULL functions.  The chip makes knows that certain operations tend to happen one after another and they added a shortcut to allow the CPU to shave some cycles when encountered.

Comment: @fuz thanks, that makes sense. They say "of accumulate operands" - does that mean it only applies to sequences like this: `a * b + c * d` (so output of a * b can be fed into accumulate operand of c * d)? So presumably it wouldn't apply to `a * b * c` (output of one `MADD` goes into another `MADD` as multiplication operand)?

Comment: @stepan I don't know actually, but your guess sounds reasonable.  Benchmark time!

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the quoted description carefully enough.  It's *not* like AMD Bulldozer-family where any FMA-unit -> FMA-unit forwarding is 1 cycle faster than to any other execution unit.  This is just for the addend of an madd.  Deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @fuz I can't benchmark unfortunately, but just found this for Apple M1 https://dougallj.github.io/applecpu/firestorm.html (by https://twitter.com/dougallj) and it says MADD has 1c lat when addition operand is from another MADD. Sounds like what is described here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Late forwarding for multiply-add operations means that the addend can be made available after the multiplication has completed rather than having to be available when the multiply-add operation begins execution. Since the multiplication itself is not data dependent on the addend, it can proceed. Since some work for the addition can be done in parallel with the multiplication (the exponent of the product will be available early and can be used with the addend's exponent to determine the amount of shift needed before addition), one may want the addend to be available before the entire product is available, but even in that case the addend is not needed until much later than the multiplicands.

By delaying the forwarding (availability) of the addend, the effective latency of dependent accumulations is reduced. This reduces the number of accumulation registers (and parallelism) one needs to cover the latency.

Comment: This is helpful, so I'm assuming late-forwarding would not happen for `a * b * c` calculation (from a*b to multiplication operand for *c).

Comment: @stepan Three-way multiply is usually not provided as a single instruction, so there would not be any opportunity for providing an operand late. Dependent multiplication series are probably also less common (integer exponentiation, a common use, would have the operands available at the start so late forwarding even if three-way multiply existed would not be as helpful).